# Get next row besides the previous row after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns like 'ID', 'value', 'counts', 'date'. After grouping by on 'ID' column I want the next row information besides the previous row.
The dataframe I have:

```
df:
ID     value      counts      date
1      1          3           1/2/2020
1      2          10          10/2/2020
1      3          5           15/2/2020
2      1          6           3/4/2020
2      2          2           10/4/2020
```

The output I want:

```
result:
ID     value      counts      date        ID1     value1    counts1     date
1      1          3           1/2/2020    1      2          10          10/2/2020
1      2          10          10/2/2020   1      3          5           15/2/2020
1      3          5           15/2/2020   nan    nan        nan         nan
2      1          6           3/4/2020    2      2          2           10/4/2020
2      2          2           10/4/2020   nan    nan        nan         nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `groupby()`+`shift()`:

```
df=df.join(df.groupby('ID').shift(-1),rsuffix='1')
```

**Note:** If you want 'ID1' column as well then you can use:

```
out=df.groupby('ID').shift(-1)
out.insert(0,'ID',df.groupby('ID')['ID'].shift(-1))
df=df.join(out,rsuffix='1')
```