# Get next row after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

My question is similar to this one : [Get next row besides the previous row after groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479601/get-next-row-besides-the-previous-row-after-groupby) but not quite the same. I'd like to get the first row appearing after a group concatenated to each row of the group.

So if I have:

```
ID     value      counts      date
1      1          3           1/2/2020
1      2          10          10/2/2020
1      3          5           15/2/2020
2      1          6           3/4/2020
2      2          2           10/4/2020
```

I'd like to have:

```
ID     value      counts      date         NextID    NextValue     NextCounts    NextDate
1      1          3           1/2/2020     2         1             6             3/4/2020
1      2          10          10/2/2020    2         1             6             3/4/2020
1      3          5           15/2/2020    2         1             6             3/4/2020
2      1          6           3/4/2020     3         4             1             11/12/2020
2      2          2           10/4/2020    3         4             1             11/12/2020
3      4          1           11/12/2020   nan       nan           nan           nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)+[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
out = df.merge(df.groupby('ID', sort=False).first()
                 .assign(ID=lambda d: d.index).shift(-1)
                 .add_prefix('Next').iloc[:-1],
               left_on='ID', right_index=True, how='left')
```

Output:

```
   ID  value  counts        date  Nextvalue  Nextcounts    Nextdate  NextID
0   1      1       3    1/2/2020        1.0         6.0    3/4/2020     2.0
1   1      2      10   10/2/2020        1.0         6.0    3/4/2020     2.0
2   1      3       5   15/2/2020        1.0         6.0    3/4/2020     2.0
3   2      1       6    3/4/2020        4.0         1.0  11/12/2020     3.0
4   2      2       2   10/4/2020        4.0         1.0  11/12/2020     3.0
5   3      4       1  11/12/2020        NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Note that I've had to change `.groupby('ID')` to `.groupby('ID',  sort=False)` in order to work as expected

Comment: @AchilleG yes, you're right, buy default this is `sort=True`